# Login detail across all pages of xamarin portable forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How can i  display Login detail of user across all pages in xamarin portable project(iOS and Andriod). I am not able to implement MasterPage concept as we use to do in ASP.net or Frame in Silverlight.
I have already gone through MasterDetailPage and I think it doesn't fulfill my requirement.

Comment: do you want to display login details on navigation bar across all the pages? or something like that?

Comment: navigation bar is fine

Comment: On the login page you can store the login details in a static class and in content page of the details page you can show the title `Title=SomeStaticClass.LoginId`

Comment: this is not what I have asked ,in ur approach if I am having 5 content page ,I have to assign login data on every page. I what to create one master page in which based on navigation I can add new child content page,, and on master  page I  will show login detail and image of user

Comment: I guess This is what you want http://imgur.com/a/1WKfx

Comment: url u mentioned doesn't work

Comment: Something like gmail app or medium app ?in master page you get the name and circle image.

Comment: yes,can you please suggest me how to achieve that

Comment: check the answer and the github repo if you need a ready template

Answer (score 2):

Create a static variable `UserName` in your `App.cs` file.

```
public class App : Application
{
    public static bool IsUserLoggedIn { get; set; }
    public static string UserName { get; set; }

    public App()
     {
        if (!IsUserLoggedIn)
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MenuPage());
        }
     }
}
```

On `LoginPage.cs` file, store the username in static variable of `App.cs` file when user login for the first time. I am assuming that you have login page with two entry fields such as username and password field along with a login button. So when user click on login button store the username from entry field as :

```
App.UserName = usernameEntry.Text.ToString();
```

On successful login authentication you might redirect to `MenuPage`.

On `MenuPage.cs` file you can easily access the static variable of `App.cs` file as :

```
public partial class MenuPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string name = App.UserName;

        }
    }
```

Likewise you can access this Static variable across any pages of your portable project. This static variable will persist till you don't remove the app from the device's current running application tray list of android/ios.

Sample project of master detail page :

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation

Sample project of Login flow :

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/LoginFlow

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that you want to do:

on login you get the image and name to display on the drawer header and you store in a constant.

your Drawer page here

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MasterDetailsPageLogin.Views.DrawerPage"
             Title="Menu"
             BackgroundColor="#8999A6"
             Padding="0,20,0,0">
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <BoxView Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               Grid.RowSpan="4"
               BackgroundColor="#8999A6"/>
      <Image
          x:Name="img"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="1"
          HorizontalOptions="Start"
          VerticalOptions="End"
          WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="75"/>
      <Label
          x:Name="myName"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listed" SeparatorColor="Transparent">
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code in your drawerpage.xaml.cs

```
    public DrawerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string howILook = Constants.Image;

            img.Source = new UriImageSource
            {
                Uri = new Uri(howILook),
                CachingEnabled = true,
                CacheValidity = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0) //Caching image for a day
            };

            myName.Text = "Welcome Mr. " + Constants.Username;
        }
```

Here is a template I have created for the login logic and master details page.
https://github.com/ak47akshaykulkarni/MasterDetailsPageLogin